# Does any Hindu scripture or work of any Acharya talk about sex education?

Tags: vedas, guru, sex, brahmacharya

Brahmanas, Kshatriya, and Vaishyas all undergo Upanayanam as early as 7 years of age. Having done Upanayanam, they become Brahmacharis.

One important vow of Brahmacharya is maintenance of celibacy, meaning no intentional emission of semen (masturbation or sex).

Here is what the Manusmriti says:

> Persons learned in the Veda and knowing the law declare that for the
>   twice-born person keeping up his vows, **the intentional emission of
>   semen means a ‘transgression of the vow.’**—(120)

This vow is very important to be maintained, as stated in the next verse:

> The spiritual power of the Religious Student (Brahmachari), who has
>   become ‘immoral,’ (Avakirnin) ‘goes away into the Maruts, Indra,
>   Bṛhaspati and Agni.—(121)

In fact, that's the reason given in the Apastamba sutras as to why no Rishis are born in kali yuga:

> The word 'austerity' (must be understood to apply) to (the observance
>   of) the rules (of studentship).
>
> If they are transgressed, study drives out the knowledge of the Veda
>   acquired already, from the (offender) and from his children.
>
> Besides he will go to hell, and his life will be shortened.
>
> **On account of that (transgression of the rules of studentship) no
>   Rishis are born amongst the men of later ages (Kali yuga).**

So my question is, is there any work of any Acharya or any Hindu scripture that talks about how to tell young Brahmachari boys to preserve their semen?

Answer (score 3):

Sex education in Hinduism is the practice of Brahmacharya, which includes the preservation of semen, and it is essential for spiritual advancement. According to the Aghori Vimalananda in "Aghora: At the Left Hand of God" by Robert E. Svoboda, pg. 261-262:

> If you want to progress from the state of being a donkey in human form, one who lives for eating and procreating, to a higher state, you must conserve your semen. If you are female you must preserve the vaginal secretions which pour out during excitement and sex. The need for celibacy is the same in both sexes. There are dozens of good reasons for Brahmacharya (celibacy).

According to Swami Sivananda in “Practice of Brahmacharya”, pg.20:

> The energy that is wasted during one sexual intercourse is tantamount to the energy that is spent in physical labour for ten days or the energy that is utilized in mental work for three days. Mark how precious is the vital fluid, semen! Do not waste this energy. Preserve it with great care. You will have wonderful vitality. **When Veerya is not used, it is all transmuted into Ojas Sakti or spiritual energy and stored up in the brain.** Western doctors know little of this salient point. Most of your ailments are due to excessive seminal wastage.

Sivananda continues:

> Mind, Prana and Veerya are one. By controlling the mind, you can control Prana and
>   semen. By controlling Prana you can control the mind and semen. By controlling semen, you
>   can control the mind and Prana.

I recommend you read the "Aghora" series by Robert E. Svoboda and “Practice of Brahmacharya” by Swami Sivananda. You can read “Practice of Brahmacharya” here (PDF): http://www.dlshq.org/download/brahmacharya.pdf or here (HTML): http://www.dlshq.org/download/brahmacharya.htm

I hope my answer was useful, please free to ask for more information.